# Haxe macro: quote field properly

Tags: macros, haxe

what is the proper way to (manually) quote a field?

consider the following example:

```
var name = "$type";
if(name.startsWith("$")) name = "@$__hx__" + name;
var e = macro {$name: "value"};
```

Instead of `name.startsWith("$")`, what is the proper way to check if the field name should be quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way to do it...

All other quoting – except for leading `$` – should already happen during reification.

```
class Test {
    static macro function makeObject(key:String, value:haxe.macro.Expr)
    {
        if (StringTools.startsWith(key, "$"))
            key = "@$__hx__" + key;
        return macro @:pos(haxe.macro.Context.currentPos()) { $key : $value };
    }

    static function main()
    {
        trace(makeObject("a", 1));
        trace(makeObject("0", 1));
        trace(makeObject(":", 1));
        trace(makeObject("$a", 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean startsWith("$") is the only case I need to care about?

Comment: @KevinResoL as far as I can understand the OCaml sources.